# jQuery plugin for page transitions with navigation history

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for quite a while now. I guess it's time to ask you guys.

What i want to achieve is a web navigation system with smooth jquery slide in/out animations.
I want to load a page with Ajax, specify its origin (top, bottom, right, left) and slide it into site while content slides out. I can do that, but what i need is a navigation history, that will remember page's relative position. I know that there is jQuery History plugin but i fear that implementing everything myself will take a lot of work and it won't be, in terms of quality, the best. I'd like to speed things up, so my question is:

Is there any jQuery plugin with similar features that you can think of?

(The only thing i can think of is jquery mobile, but should I use it with non-mobile application? Does it support all common pc browsers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Alman's BBQ sounds like a pretty good fit for your needs :)
-> http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I gave it a look and it covers the history part of my problem. but what i actualy look for is a plugin that incudes support for both history and page transitions. Simply because i want to achive effect where clicking the back button invokes transition opposite to the last one( if current content used  slide in from right, back button needs to make it slide back to right). If i won't find anything I'll make my own animations with BBQ plugin for history handling.

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward method of accomplishing your task. Just bind your animations to the onhashchange event. When the user clicks the back button the event is fired and the animation is playing. Gives you 1. Maximum control ... 2. Maximum pleasure for building it yourself :)

Comment: Is there any way i can easily store my information using this plugin that are specific for each page transition? I mean when i click back button, plugin doesn't know the transition animation history. It keeps only navigation history. How can i connect those two?

Comment: Depends on how flexible you want to write your codebase. You could build a nice little datastructure that is storing your site specific data. Maybe nesting it, so you can traverse this object and calculate the direction your animation should go. Start with an allround animation function you could call like `move("back"/"forth")` and build the rest on top of that

Comment: What do you think of placing an attribute into div : <div transition="back/forth">/<div>, locating it in onhashchange event and depending on this div being already loaded or not calling proper animation?

Comment: Call your attribute `<div data-transition="">` So that you can get the stored information easily with `$("div").data("transition")` or `$.data("div", transition)` I also see a lot of custom markup. If you just got a few elements, this solution seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

This might be more than you need but it's pretty slick. Turn.js allows for an iBooks style page curl in HTML5 and manages the history state via hashtag.

http://www.turnjs.com/#home

Comment: Yeah, an awsome plugin. I'll remember this one. But sadly I can't use it for my application. I need slides and not book-like turns because I'm trying to implement metro-like interface.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/
It allows for deeplinking with jquery so you can append to the url in the hash tag.